# To have or not to have more than one models.ImageField in my model

Tags: django

I'm able to upload images successfully.

Now I want to do the following:
develop a Celery's task that will convert an uploaded image to 3 different dimensions (say, 300x300, 120x120, and 48x48).

I'm wondering what's the best approach:

To change my Image class to have just on object with 4 models.ImageField fields (for the original and the 3 new versions of it) or to keep it with just one models.ImageField and create extra objects on database.

I'm wondering about memory implications:

In case I opt for the first option (add extra ImageField fields), when I retrieve the object from database, all fields will be read at once.
It's not a problem (the fields in database will contain just strings with the images path).

The point is: will django create 4 instances of image objects right after it retrieved data from database or just when I access the respective ImageField?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you answered your own question already. The database entries will only contain path. So it's not really a problem. Your second question was when does the data get retrieved. It depends on how you get your object. For example, `object = Model.objects.get(id=1)` will get the object in memory.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I know that MyObject = Model.objects.get(id=1) will instantiate an object. My doubt is: if this object has 4 fields of type ImageField, will all these fields be instantiated as objects at the moment I retrieved myObject or just when I do call the ImageFields explicitly (eg,: myObject.image01, myObject.image02, and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one `ImageField` and use `easy_thumbnails` for the thumbnail generation.

You can predefine thumbnails using `aliases`.

Then follow the Celery guidelines [here](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#asynchronous-pregeneration).

Comment: I'll follow your advise and use easy_thumbnails. Thanks.